# addEventListener: Unsupported Operation: This API cannnot be used on this component

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console, console

my goal is to keep only one contact TAB opened in Console all the time , if there is already a tab opened i need to close it and open the new tab.

I have a VF section on standard detail page and i added addEventListener for OPEN_TAB. When the EventListener function executes on TAB open getting the error saying un supported API function. does it means i can't add EventListener on a VF section? if so is there in other work around for this?

```
function getAllTabIds() {
        // get all Tab ID's 
        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabIds(closeAlltabs);
    }  
    var closeAlltabs = function closeAlltabs(results) {

       alert('closeAlltabs Called'+result.ids);
        var tabId = result.id;
    };
     sforce.console.addEventListener(sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.OPEN_TAB,
     getAllTabIds, { tabId : sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId() });
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit late, but hopefully this might be useful in the future. 
The sforce.console object in embedded VF pages on standard layouts doesn't support adding listeners if you're using Integration Toolkit v 30 or above. Since you want to listen for the standard OPEN_TAB event, I guess lowering the version is not an option. 
The workaround I can think of is to implement the listener code on a Custom Console Component which is linked linked to a VF page.